# Set value using loc on part of multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

I set multiindex on dataframe

```
df.set_index(['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

then I want to set some value to all rows, where index 'A' equals 'foo'

```
df.loc[df['A'] == 'foo'] = 5
```

it raises following error:

```
KeyError: 'A'
```

Comment: Because `A` is not in columns it is in index.

Comment: @SandeepKadapa how to refer to A?